# mysql takes too long on "checking permissions"

Tags: mysql

We have about 20 databases with about 8000 tables each. Modifying the software is not an option (it is bought), and it seems most of the cpu is consumed by "checking permissions". While the s/w accesses the DB the DB cpus get all to 100%, while processlist report 99% of queries stuck in "checking permissions". Any idea on how to improve this, or how to disable permissions in mysql altogether?

Tables are innodb file_per_table, table_open_cache=60000,    table_definition_cache=50000 The database has only 3 users. Nearly    all of the queries are like the one below. DB runs on Centos 6.5

```
mysql> SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `XXXX` LIKE 'HISTORY_CONFIG';
+---------------------------------------+------------+
| Tables_in_XXXX (HISTORY_CONFIG) | Table_type |
+---------------------------------------+------------+
| HISTORY_CONFIG                        | BASE TABLE |
+---------------------------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                                    |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.16267675 | SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `XXXX` LIKE 'HISTORY_CONFIG' |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show profile context switches;
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| Status               | Duration | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary |
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| starting             | 0.000077 |                 0 |                   0 |
| checking permissions | 0.000014 |                 0 |                   0 |
| checking permissions | 0.000013 |                 0 |                   0 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000038 |                 0 |                   0 |
| init                 | 0.000017 |                 0 |                   0 |
| System lock          | 0.000015 |                 0 |                   0 |
| optimizing           | 0.000013 |                 0 |                   0 |
| statistics           | 0.000017 |                 0 |                   0 |
| preparing            | 0.000016 |                 0 |                   0 |
| executing            | 0.000015 |                 0 |                   0 |
| checking permissions | 0.111432 |               360 |                 189 |
| Sending data         | 0.000042 |                 0 |                   0 |
| end                  | 0.000017 |                 0 |                   0 |
| query end            | 0.000013 |                 0 |                   0 |
| closing tables       | 0.000012 |                 0 |                   0 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000016 |                 0 |                   0 |
| closing tables       | 0.000013 |                 0 |                   0 |
| freeing items        | 0.050857 |               129 |                  59 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000043 |                 0 |                   0 |
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
19 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**
Solved by creating a mysql-proxy lua script which smartly caches successfull table hits and answers instantly. This was an application-specific fix though.

Comment: How many user accounts do you have?    select count(*) from mysql.user;

Comment: As I state in the description, we only have 3 accounts. I tried adding 10 accounts but this didn't raise times, so it must be something else.

Comment: 3 or 13 accounts shouldn't matter.

How many GRANTs do you have?

What is the app doing (dropping tables, perhaps?)?

Comment: the app has lots of alter table requests, and some create/drop tables.

Comment: Perhaps this lock is the culprit?  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/06/16/slow-drop-table/

Comment: Most waiting is from show full tables, which perhaps  trigger some mysql busy loop.

Comment: it seems SHOW full tables just re-reads the filesystem to find tables. So that creates huge I/O even on cached fs. That may be related to "checking permissions".